# How do you compile C++ using a docker container to create Linux binary while on Mac OS

Tags: docker, tensorflow, clion

I am currently trying to use Tensorflow's C++ api to build a binary to run on Ubuntu, but I am on a Mac.

I was turned in the direction of this [dockerImage](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) to use to build tensorflow C++ binaries. However. I am new to C++ and building things and can't figure out how to write code on my Mac and the build with the container.

I have all the same versions of software both on Mac and in the container. GCC, Bazel, CMake, and Tensorflow.

Also using Clion to do my developing on not Eclipse. Can't seem to find the .h files I need to link to my project so I have auto completion.

Comment: Without something in the way of diagnostic errors this is really hard to answer.

Comment: @tadman there are no errors because I can't figure out how to even run a local file in my docker container in a certain directory. I have code(on local mac) that needs to be compiles on inside of a docker cantainer to be compiled into the correct Binary.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem (might be wrong):  you need to mount your code into the docker container.

Let us say that you have your code on your mac in `/home/user/cool-project`.
(I forgot where HOME is on the mac.)

Then you run the container:  you are doing something like `docker container run --name mybuildcontainer ...`.  Add something like `--mount type=bind,source=/home/user/cool-project,destination=/src`.

Then when you `docker exec -it mybuildcontainer ls /src` it should list your source code.

Obviously change `/homer/user/cool-project` to where you actually have code stored on your mac and `/src` to where you need it to be on the container.